# How do I change a character of my matrix? (Without Numpy)

Tags: python

I'm doing an exercice that requires me to make a movie theather room matrix by user input and book seats on it, but I just can't find how I do it anywere.

```
lf = int(input('Informe a quantidade de fileiras: '))
cf = int(input('Informe quantos assentos por fileira: '))

colunas = ['  A ', 'B ', 'C ', 'D ', 'E ', 'F ', 'G ', 'H ', 'I ', 'J ', 'K ', 'L ',
                   'M ', 'N ', 'O ', 'P ', 'Q ', 'R ', 'S ', 'T ', 'U ', 'V ', 'W ', 'X ', 'Y ', 'Z ']
cinema = []
c = 0
for cont in range(0, cf):
    print(colunas[cont], end='')
print()

# entrada input usuario
for i in range(lf):  # loop para linhas
    a = []
    for j in range(cf):  # loop para colunas
        a.append('.')
        cinema.append(a)

# impressão matriz
for i in range(lf):
    c += 1
    if c < 10:
        print(c, end=' ')
    if c >= 10:
        print(c, end='')

    for j in range(cf):
        print(cinema[i][j], end=" ")

    print()
print('  ============================')
print('  |           TELA           |')
print('  ============================')
```

How can I change the '.' to 'x' to show that the seat is booked?

Comment: You're gonna have an issue: you probably want `cinema.append(a)` to be tabbed back one tab, it shouldn't be in the inner `for` loop.

Comment: And to change `.` to `x`, just do `cinema[i][j] = 'x'` for which ever location is selected

Comment: Thank you! With this I found out that I have something in my code that is writing over this, that's why it isn't working.